# React - How to apply multiple values inside style

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-hooks

I have a certain component named `ThemeDoc` inside this component there is a `context`, `localStorage`, `hooks`, `maps` and whatnot, but in the end I get the value of the hooks inside a component named `SideBar`. I decided that there is no need to demonstrate the contents of the `ThemeDoc` component in order not to complicate my code and question, but I will attach a link of my project on the github if you want you can see [GitHub Project](https://github.com/SuroZaqaryan/Portfolio_v_1.0.git). So as I just mentioned, I get the value of the `hooks` from the `ThemeDoc` component for the `SideBar` component, they look like this

```
const {SideBarValue, SideBarWallpaperValue, SideBarColor} = React.useContext(CounterContext);

const [SideBarTheme, SetSideBarTheme] = SideBarValue;
const [SideBarBackground] = SideBarWallpaperValue;
const [SideBarColorTheme, SetSideBarColor] = SideBarColor;
```

These values are used to change the color of the `SideBar`.

```
<div style={{background: SideBarTheme}}>
  ...
</div>
```

It all looks like this

[image]

Please see there are two values for `SideBarTheme` and `SideBarColorTheme`, `SideBarTheme` changes the background of the site to a gradient and the `SideBarColorTheme` only changes the SideBar color. As you can see I successfully applied the `SideBarTheme` value inside jsx and everything works fine for me

```
<div style={{background: SideBarTheme}}>
  ...
</div>
```

But I can’t use `SideBarColorTheme`, I don’t know how to do it, here is my full-fledged code if you need to tell me I will provide the `ThemeDoc` component

**SideBar.jsx**

```
function SideBar(props) {
    const {someValue} = useContext(SideBarContext);

    const {SideBarValue, SideBarColor} = React.useContext(CounterContext);

    const [SideBarTheme, SetSideBarTheme] = SideBarValue;
    const [SideBarColorTheme, SetSideBarColor] = SideBarColor;

    return (
            <div style={{background: SideBarTheme, backdropFilter: `blur(${someValue}px)`}}>
               ...
            </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I don't exactly get what you meant by sidebar color? You mean border color?

Comment: Your question isn't clear at all. Are you trying to apply both the value of `SideBarTheme` and `SideBarColorTheme` to the css [background](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) value? As that will not work, you can only assign it a single value, you'll need to merge the values yourself.

Comment: No, SideBar color, SideBarColorTheme applies a certain color in my case, red, I need to apply this value for the background

Comment: You understood correctly, I need to apply these values for css, but I don't quite understand how to do it